# XML Parsing Error: no root element found

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I am trying to search for all properties in a database that are in one suburb. I have read that it has something to do with the HTML code 204 but I still do not undertand what to do or what it really means. I have not done any JS or PHP in a while so this may be a really silly error but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Please Help!

Here is my JS code:

```
function basicSearch(){

    //Connect Script to the PHP
    var urlLink = "basicSearch.php";
    //Get search parameters:
    var searchAreaBar = document.getElementById("searchAreaBar").value;

    //define the parameters to send to php
    var strParameters = "searchAreaBar="+searchAreaBar + "&sid=" + Math.random();

        // define the options for the AJAX request
        var objOptions = {
        // use method post
        method: "post",
        // use strParameters as the parameters
        parameters: strParameters,
        // if successfil call fuction(objXHR)
        onSuccess: function(objXHR) {

            // if objXHR. responseText = yes
            if(objXHR.responseText=='Yes'){

                alert("Success!");

            }
            else{

                alert("Error! No Properties Found!");

            }
        }
    }

    // define the AJAX request object
    var objRequest = new Ajax.Request(urlLink,objOptions);

}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    //Link the username and password:
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "12345", "realestate") or die ('Connection to database failed: ' . mysql_error());
    //Extract variables for request parameters:
    extract($_REQUEST);

    //Define the query:
    $BasicSearch = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Suberb='$searchAreaBar'";
    //Run the query:
    $resDasicSearch = mysqli_query($BasicSearch) or die(mysql_error());
    //SET intCount to number of rows in result:
    $intCount = mysqli_num_rows($resDasicSearch);

    //If intCount is greater than 0:
    if($intCount > 0){
        //Echo Yes:
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else{

        //Echo no:
        echo "No";

    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysqli_query` requires two arguments - the db connection being one of them and the sql statement the other

Comment: I added $connect but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that the browser's compiler was "commenting out" all the php and adding empty HTML tags. It was then getting confused as there was an "empty" document.

This was because the website (including JS, PHP and HTML files) were being stored and run from a local directory. For example:

the URL read:
**file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/"Project Name"/Index.html**

the correct URL is:
**localhost/"Project Name"**

IF you are using XAMPP, the folder containing all your project files need to be placed in the htdocs folder in the xampp directory.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be using an Ajax function that is not shown it is hard to determine the root cause of the problem because nothing above, as far as I can tell, would yield the error you allude to in the title of the posting - namely "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" - I wonder therefore if there should be a configuration option in `Ajax.Request` that needs to be set to deal with a basic string response?

That aside you might be able to make use of the following - perhaps even for diagnosis purposes.

```
<?php

    /*
        ---------------
        basicSearch.php
        ---------------
    */

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'admin'; 
    $dbpwd  =   '12345'; 
    $dbname =   'realestate';

    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $sql='select * from `properties` where `suberb`=?';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $searcharea = $_POST['searchAreaBar'];

        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $searcharea );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $suberbs );
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo $stmt->num_rows()==0 ? "No" : "Yes";

    }
    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();
?>

<script>
    /* reuseable utility ajax function */
    function ajax( method, url, params, callback, options ){
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )callback.call( this, xhr.response, options, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
        };

        var async=params.hasOwnProperty('async') ? params.async : true;
        var query=[];

        for( var n in params )query.push(n+'='+params[n]);

        switch( method.toLowerCase() ){
            case 'post': query=query.join('&'); break;
            case 'get': url+='?'+query.join('&'); params=null; break;
        }

        xhr.open( method.toUpperCase(), url, async );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send( params );
    }


    /* function that does the search */
    function function basicSearch(){
        /* configure the parameters to be used in the ajax request */
        var method='post';
        var url='basicSearch.php';
        var params={
            searchAreaBar:document.getElementById('searchAreaBar').value,
            sid:Math.random()
        };
        var callback=function(r,o,h){
            alert( r ? 'Success' : 'Error! No Properties Found!' )
        }
        var options={};

        /* call the ajax function */
        ajax.call(this,method, url, params, callback, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I meet this error in Firefox's console, that is so simple, while all my API return JSON, one of my API return text/html and it causes Firefox show up that error!

I have changed my NodeJS Express code:

```
res.end('');
```

To

```
res.json({});
```

ANd it is okay now! Hope it can help someone!